# how to Install opencv module

Tags: opencv, unix, installation

I already installed opencv via "apt-get install opencv" and now I want to use a contrib module (aruco). Is there a way to simply install the module, without having to re-install opencv?

(i am coding in c++, on raspberry pi)

I tried to use directly the source files and compile them together with my other files but that did not worked out really well

Also, any script that uninstalls and does a clean reinstall with the contrib packages will be fine for me. (I struggled to build from source but I was getting errors and stuff and I installed opencv with apt-get, that is why I try to avoid re-installing from source.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

I discovered this only after re-installing and re-building opencv with the contrib files but there was a much more shorter (and obvious) path.
I went on the home page of this [project](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) and I was able to build that from source (with opencv pre-installed).
My guess is that all the contrib files can be builded and installed after the installation of opencv given the fact that all of them only rely on the main build, and are not and essential component of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build Opencv from source you can follow the instructions [here](http://arijitgeek.me/index.php/2016/06/24/install-opencv-3-1-0-with-python-2-7-on-aws-ubuntu-ec2-instance/)

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON2=ON \
-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR= /usr/include/python2.7 \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/../path/to/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Do check the Cmake output that it don't gives an error of contrib_mdules not found

```
/path/to/opencv_contrib/modules \
```

A week ago I followed the instruction for my Raspberry pi 2 and it works

But the whole process took me around 4hrs to complete . and also for 3.1 you need a little more than 3 Gig free space so its preferable that you get a 16gig MicroSD :)

Comment: as I said in the question, I need to do the coding in c++, not python. Will this also install the libraries for g++?

Comment: any way, I was looking for a solution to add the modules to the pre-installed opencv, not re-install everything. thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you build from source it always installs c++ and the python wrapper is the bonus :) I don't think there is a solution to add the modules in your pre existing installation .